# HTML Form sending data to SQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, sql-server

**When submitted, a new row gets added to the 'servers' table, but every data says '0' instead of the data I inputted..** I'm using VARCHAR64 for the rows..

**Form.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="db.php" method="post">
server id: <input type="text" name="post_serverid">
server ip: <input type="text" name="post_serverip">
<input type="submit>
</body>
</html>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","toplist");

//Checking the connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
  echo "Cold not connect to SQL Database: " + mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO servers (serverid, serverip) VALUES ('$_POST['post_serverid']', '$_POST['post_serverip']')");

?>
```

Comment: Strangely enough, **mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO form (name, dob)
VALUES ('$_POST[post_name]', '$_POST[post_dob]')"); works**. But when I replace NAME with SERVERID, and replace DOB with SERVERIP, the inputted data doesn't insert..

Comment: @GangDonIt, in the future, please do not post screen captures of your code. Please copy and paste the code into the body of the question.

Comment: *"But when I replace NAME with SERVERID, and replace DOB with SERVERIP, the inputted data doesn't insert.."* --- that's because you need to change your column names accordingly. @GangDonIt - Rename your `SERVERID` column to `NAME` and `SERVERIP` to `DOB` or vice-versa.

Comment: @Fred-ii- of course I did that.

Comment: Well you wrote in your comment above that it works. @GangDonIt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**From OP's comment:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412749/html-form-sending-data-to-sql-table/21413170#comment32301743_21412749)

*"Strangely enough, `mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO form (name, dob) VALUES ('$_POST[post_name]', '$_POST[post_dob]')");` works."*

*"But when I replace `NAME` with `SERVERID`, and replace `DOB` with `SERVERIP`, the inputted data doesn't insert."*

---

The problem is, you need to change your POST variables and column names accordingly.

Rename your `NAME` column to `SERVERID` and `DOB` column to `SERVERIP`.

and `post_name` to `serverid` and `post_dob` to `serverip`

---

The new query can now be done this way:

```
$serverid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['serverid']);
$serverip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['serverip']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `servers` (`serverid`, `serverip`) VALUES ('$serverid', '$serverip');";

mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Using this method will help prevent against [**SQL injection.**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Answer (score 1):

**First: NEVER just throw user data straight into your database without validating / cleansing it first.**

Next, you've got some odd punctuation going on in your mysqli_query(). Try this:

```
$serverid = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['serverid']);
$serverip = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['serverip']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO servers (serverid, serverip) VALUES('$serverid', '$serverip');";

mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: I receive the error: Undefined:mysqli and Call to a member function real_escape_string() on line 10. Line 10 is "$serverid = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['serverid']);"

Comment: It's because you need to change `$mysqli->real_escape_string` to `$con->real_escape_string` @GangDonIt

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Sorry. @Fred-ii-is right about $con vs $mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `$_POST['key']` instead of `$_POST[key]`

Comment: This is comment, not answer

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this brought up more errors.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is an associative array, you need to access the keys with single or double quotes.

Example:

change your query to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO servers (serverid, serverip) VALUES ('".$_POST['post_serverid']."','".$_POST['post_serverip']."')";

mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Also, you are currently volunerable to SQL injection. I'd suggest to use a prepared statement or at least escape the $_POST variables before inserting it to the DB.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, you can access values with either single or double quotes - it's just that double quotes allow the contents to be interpreted so using `$` and similar can be problematic if not escaped properly

Answer (score 0):

```
$serverip=$_POST['post_serverid'];
$serverid=$_POST['post_serverip'];
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO servers (serverid, serverip) VALUES ('$serverid','$serverid')");
```

Try this, it should work